# Refactor Solution Folder to New Solution

Tags: refactoring, resharper, visual-studio-2015, automated-refactoring

I've got a a fairly large project with many code files in Visual Studio 2015.
This folder contains lots of structures and classes that have no ties to the solution they're in, but need to be moved to an external solution to resolve a circular dependency issue.

Is there any way to automatically refactor a solution folder in VS to a new project? Resharper/other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that while resharper is enabled, you can right click on a solution folder and select "Move" to automatically refactor a solution folder and it's contents..